# Filtering objects with same ID in long format

Tags: r, dplyr

I had a dataset with thousands of samples (rows) with thousands of objects (columns) where the entries are different properties, with more than one propertie per entry (I know, not very tidy). 
Now I had to switch to the long format with onlyfour coloumn remaining. Before I could easyly filter for samples which satisfy several conditions.

In the long format there is a Problem, if I want to filter for example all Objects O1 which are red Fords. In wide format I could simply add a AND condition but in the long I have to use the OR condition for Car and Color, but then I'll get samples where only one condition is satisfied.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  sample = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
  object = c("O1", "O1", "O2", "O1", "O2", "O1", "O1"),
  property = c("Color", "Car", "Weather", "Car", "Animal", "Color", "Car"),
  value = c("red", "Ford", "Rain", "Ford", "Dog", "red", "Volkswagen")
)
df %>% dplyr::filter((object == "O1" & property == "Color" & value == "red") |
                       object == "O1" & property == "Car" & value == "Ford")
```

Now I'll get also samples where the color is red but, the car isn't a For and vice verta.

Is there a way to do it without joining two filtered tables?

PS: Since I want to create a dynamic search in a shiny app, I can't simply group by sample and check if the count is two.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have to differentiate between Color and car (assuming that you don't have a color called *Ford* or a car called *red*). You can choose the `value` to be either `red` or `Ford` while object is `O1`, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 filter(value %in% c('red', 'Ford') & object == 'O1')


#  sample object property value
#1      A     O1    Color   red
#2      A     O1      Car  Ford
#3      B     O1      Car  Ford
#4      C     O1    Color   red
```

I might be overthinking it, but here is a solution based on your requirements that does not use the length being 2,

```
df %>% 
 group_by(sample) %>% 
 mutate(new = toString(value)) %>% 
 filter(grepl('\\bred, Ford\\b', new) & object == 'O1') %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 4
>   sample object property value
>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>
> 1 A      O1     Color    red  
> 2 A      O1     Car      Ford
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But still I only want to have samples where both is satisfied, color and car. So I only want the entries with sample = "A" to be left.